# KVM USB Passthrough and Zydas usb wireless adapter: device or resource busy

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, kvm-virtualization, usb

i'm tring to setup a kernel testing virtualmachine for a 80211 module.

i start my machine with this command:

```
kvm -m 512 -net nic -net vde -usb -usbdevice host:0ace:1215  ktesting.img
```

i set up a kvm image with debian connected to a vde_switch at the eth0 interface and with a

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 0ace:1215 ZyDAS ZD1211B 802.11g
```

i installed the 'zd1211-firmware' and give the right permissions in /dev/bus/usb.

the wlan0 interface go up:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:12:34:56  
          inet addr:192.168.2.15  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe12:3456/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:7 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1706 (1.6 KiB)  TX bytes:1458 (1.4 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:72:71:dc:a3  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

but when i try to use wpa_supplicant to connect to my router:

```
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c conf
```

i got this output(stderr and stout):

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed 
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: Trying to associate with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f (SSID='home' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: Association request to the driver failed
wlan0: Authentication with 00:0c:f6:83:e8:9f timed out.
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 2 received
```

i tried using the wifi adapter on my laptop to connect to the same network with the same config file installing only the zd1211-firmware and it work perfectly.
it's not a problem of my compiled kernel as the problem persist with the stock debian kernel (wheezy)

Comment: There are some ports that still busy in some situations. We are suffering the same thing in usb-printers.
Stay tunned in the KVM mailing list ;)

Comment: it's a bug in kvm version 1.1,i solved it with an update to the 1.3 version after a few try for reproduce it with the Debian maintainer